# Webmaster meta tag issue in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I used **meta-tag-manager** plugin for add keywords and I have added webmaster meta tag but cannot get it to appear in my website

> ```
> if I tried in "all pages" it will appear but
> ```
>
> if i Try in "front page"  nothing appears.

How i can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Latest Version of Meta Tag Manager plugin i.e. 2.0.2. Because as per plugins's changelog there was a bug in previous version.

```
2.0.2 - fixed front page meta tags not showing if using a static front page.
```

Reference : https://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-tag-manager/changelog/

Comment: Can you share URL.